# Issue with style.display = "block" in all latest browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

In JavaScript, I run `element.style.display = "block"` where `element` is an `<asp:control>`, `<tr>` or `<td>` DOM element. When I do this, the element displays on a new line. How can I avoid this behaviour, either by using JavaScript or CSS?

For reference, the JavaScript function I am using is below:

```
function hideEdit()
{
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnEdit").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnRegisterMe").style.display="block";
}
```

And my ASP.NET element which creates my HTML:

```
<asp:Button
    ID="btnRegisterMe"
    runat="server"
    CssClass="button_bg_primary"
    OnClick="btnRegisterMe_Click"
    Text="Register"
    OnClientClick="return imagevalidation();"
    TabIndex="94"
    meta:resourcekey="btnRegisterMeResource1" />
```

Comment: `display:block` is supposed to create a new line. Why do you set it to block if you don't want it to be a block level element?

Comment: dot forget to mark it as accepted if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

to over come this you need `display:inline` instead of block

display : block - is create block for the content and creates new line for it.

display : inline - not create new line but it arrange your content in same line.

Answer (score 0):

CSS 2.1 introduced `display: inline-block;` which is the best of both worlds here.

First, it treats the inside of the element as a `block`, allowing it to have `width` and `height`. The element itself is still `inline`, however, meaning it won't wrap onto a newline as you're seeing.

W3Schools has [an in-depth explanation about `display: inline-block`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).

You can set the property in JavaScript the same way you're currently setting it to `block` like so:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnRegisterMe")
        .style.display = "inline-block";
```